# MediaWiki API: How to get a list of newly created pages?

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia

I'm trying to get a list of newly created pages on the English Wikipedia from
here:

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:NewPages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special%3aNewPages)

I tried querying the above title via MediaWiki API, but it doesn't support
querying the titles in the "Special:" namespace:

[http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query#Missing_and_invalid_titles](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aQuery#Missing_and_invalid_titles)

Is there any workaround I could employ to get the list of the newly created
wiki pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [the `recentchanges` API module](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aRecentchanges) with `rctype=new`.